# SqlServer Trigger to add multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER .[dbo].[trgAfterInsertComment] 
   ON  .[dbo].[Comment] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @Id int;
    declare @LoanId int;
    declare @CopyId int;
    declare @CustomerId int;
    declare @Comment nvarchar(255);

    --DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    select @Id = Id from inserted
    select @LoanId = LoanId from inserted
    --select @CopyId = CopyId from deleted
    --select @CustomerId = CustomerId from deleted
    select @Comment = Comment from inserted
    -- OPEN cur

    --FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Id, @ISBN, @Purchase_Date

    --WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        -- your business logic 
    Declare @Title nvarchar(255);
    select @Title = (Select Title from Book where ISBN = (select ISBN from copy where Id = (select CopyId from Loan where Id = @LoanId)))
    select @CustomerId = (Select CustomerId from Loan where Id = @LoanId)
    select @CopyId = (Select CopyId from Loan where Id = @LoanId)
    insert into Activity("Heading", "Date")

    values(Concat('New Comment added - Id: ', @Id, ' Title: ', @Title, ' Copy Id: ', @CopyId, ' Customer Id: ', @CustomerId, ' Comment: ', @Comment), GETDATE())

        --FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Id, @ISBN, @Purchase_Date

    --END

    --CLOSE cur
    --DEALLOCATE cur
    end
```

As you can see I have commented out a cursor that I was using to handle multiple inserts. Could someone tell me how I can handle multiple inserts without the cursor, as after reading around I see that using a cursor is a bad idea?

With the above trigger, if I try to insert multiple lines like this:

```
USE [Library]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comment]
           ([LoanId]
           ,[Comment])
     VALUES
           (47, 'test'),
           (48, 'test'),
           (50, 'test')
GO
```

Only the first row is inserted into my Activity table. Thanks for any help

Comment: "the first row is inserted" - you're not even guaranteed that. Because you're running independent selects to populate your variables, there's no guarantee that they all correspond to the *same* row from `inserted`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it differently, Damien?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shift it to be set based, using variables and a loop will cause you issues. Can't test the below, but something like:

```
INSERT INTO Activity
        (   
            Heading , 
            [Date]
        )
SELECT      CONCAT('New Comment added - Id: ', I.id, ' Title: ', COALESCE(B.Title,''), ' Copy Id: ', COALESCE(L.CopyID,''), ' Customer Id: ', COALESCE(L.CustomerID,''))    ,
            GETDATE()
FROM        inserted    AS  I
LEFT JOIN   Loan        AS  L   ON  I.loanId    =   L.loanId
LEFT JOIN   Copy        AS  C   ON  C.Id        =   L.CopyId
LEFT JOIN   Book        AS  B   ON  B.ISBN      =   C.ISBN;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this querying inserted table directly.

```
insert into [dbo].[Comment] (LoanId, Comment)
select LoanId, Comment from inserted
```

You can change the select query to more complex to achieve the result using query only.

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz, thanks for your post. But for each row in inserted, I want to add one row to my activity table. I'm not sure if your answer fits this?

Comment: @DevDave it does, SQL server works in sets. If you are thinking from a programming POV you will think of foreach loops to add to a table, but SQL doesn't need to work like that. If you use INSERT with a SELECT, a row will be inserted for each row the SELECT brings back. This is the way to use SQL, loops and cursors have a place, but should be avoided where they can be.